# Why does my WebSocket message handler always get React state hook variable's initial value?

Tags: reactjs

In my App.js React functional component I want to create a single WebSocket for communications with a web server.  It gets passed, as a prop, to some subcomponents to listen on for different kinds of updates from the server.  While the socket works and my subcomponents get all the messages, any changes from the message handlers to React.useState variables is gone the next time the message handler is called.

In the code below, console.log always prints 0, for msgCount even though I increment it in the method and I see that I'm getting 1200 messages from the server.

```
export default function App(props) {
    const [webSocket, setWebSocket] = React.useState(null);
    const [msgCount, setMsgCount] = React.useState(0);

    function getWebSocket() {
        let ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8083/");
        ws.onmessage = function (event) {
            console.log("msgCount=" + msgCount);
            setMsgCount(msgCount + 1);
        };
        return ws;
    }

    let ws = webSocket;
    if (ws === null && loggedInUser !== null) {
        ws = getWebSocket();
        setWebSocket(ws);
    }
    return (
        <div>Hello World</div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the deferred form of `setState`: `setX(prevX => prevX + 1)`. This doesn't use the value of the state variable at the time it's declared, instead, it stores a function (`prevX => prevX + 1`) that is passed the up-to-date value any time it is invoked.

Specifically, in your case, this might look like

```
export default function App(props) {
    const [webSocket, setWebSocket] = React.useState(null);
    const [msgCount, setMsgCount] = React.useState(0);

    // this is here just for an accurate log statement; it triggers whenever `msgCount` is changed
    React.useEffect(() => {
       console.log("msgCount in effect:", msgCount);
    }, [msgCount])

    function getWebSocket() {
        let ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8083/");
        ws.onmessage = function (event) {
            // This will still log 0 because `msgCount` is fixed here and never redefined
            console.log("msgCount in onmessage:", msgCount);
            // but this "deferred" form of `setState` updates the value based on its current value, so is not using `msgCount` in the current scope.
            setMsgCount(count => count + 1);
        };
        return ws;
    }

    let ws = webSocket;
    if (ws === null && loggedInUser !== null) {
        ws = getWebSocket();
        setWebSocket(ws);
    }
    return (
        <div>Hello World</div>
    );
}
```

It's probably advisable to put the `getWebSocket` call in an effect as well:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const ws = webSocket;
    if (ws === null && loggedInUser !== null) { ... }
}, [loggedInUser]);
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew - this actually solved my problem.  Using a function to get access to the current value of msgCount did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can't update a websocket on runtime. You could see it as a rocket, you can't change the way a rocket is build when it has been launched into space. If you pass your state value when it launches, it will launch with that value and it won't change it. It can detect changes on the server and send a message to the front-end, but it can't receive anything from the front-end.

A workaround here is to stop the websocket connection and reinitialise it everytime the value you need changes, but I wouldn't suggest doing this unless it's really necessary.

If you really need to change the params of your websocket on runtime, I suggest taking a peek at this [issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1505) on GitHub.

Comment: But I'm not trying to change the WebSocket at runtime - I'm trying to change the front-end's state.  In this example just a count, but in the real application, the messages coming from the server need to be stored in a component's array so that the render() method can display them.

Comment: It actually doesn't matter that it's a WebSocket in this case. You only call `getWebSocket` one time (by design) -- after that `webSocket`, and therefore `ws` is not `null` so that function does not get called again. Thus the callback function `ws.onevent` has been defined and is *not* tied to your component's state. `ws` could be a websocket or a plain Object, result would be the same.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewSchwartz - maybe I should have asked my question differently: how do I tie arriving messages back into the component's state?  How does a component which needs to display the current *and* previous messages which came over the socket do this?  Do I need to use global variables?  I'm new to Javascript/React, so advanced apologies if this has an obvious answer.

Comment: Caveat: I don't know much about web sockets, but I think I can black box that for here. One way I'd consider is to create a new file, let's say `WebSocketManager.js`. This file will have a class `WebSocketManager` of which you will create and export one instance: `export const webSocketManager = WebSocketManager.new();`. This class can keep an internal data member called `messageCount` and a `webSocket`. Anywhere you `import { webSocketManager }` it will refer to the same instance (you export/import the instance, not the class), and thus a shared value of `message_count`.

Comment: Actually there's another approach I just looked into that is better suited to what you're actually trying to do. I'll post below.